# c# list<t>; how to add objects like a foreach loop but without foreach?

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# and need help with lists and objects.

Severe edit as suggested..

what I really want to do is

```
List<Item> MyList = new List<Item>();

Item MyItem = new Item();

MyItem.Colour = "red";
MyList.Add(MyItem);
MyItem.Colour = "blue";
MyList.Add(MyItem);
MyItem.Colour = "white";
MyList.Add(MyItem);
```

And my list will now contain 3 elements - red, blue, white.

I think I can do this by:

Item MyItem = new Item();

```
MyItem.Colour = "red";
MyList.Add(MyItem);

MyIten = new Item();
MyItem.Colour = "blue";

MyItem = new Item();
MyList.Add(MyItem);

MyItem = new Item();
MyItem.Colour = "white";
MyList.Add(MyItem);
```

Again, this is simplified. With my real data there are a lot more elements.

I'll try that out;

TIA - Andrew

Comment: sounds like your problem stems from where you read from the text file.  if you have a neat way to do this then the rest will happen easily.  want to post what you have for that?

Comment: Could you please provide the concrete listing of the text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, I'm guessing you have a scoping problem. Your code should look something like this... pay particular attention to where each variable is set.  Also, with these types of scenarios it is often helpful to create a static factory method called `Parse` that constructs the object from a string.

```
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);

Job myJob = null;
Detail myDetail = null;
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var lineType = getLineType(line);
    switch(lineType){
        case Job:
           myJob = new Job();
           break;
        case newDetail:
           if(myDetail != null)
           {
               myJob.Details.Add(myDetail); 
           }
           Detail myDetail = new Detail();
           break;
        case continueDetail:
           //set some detail properties
           break;
   }
```

}

One more time

```
List<Item> MyList = new List<Item>();
Item MyItem = new Item();
MyItem.Colour = "red";
MyList.Add(MyItem);
MyItem = new Item(); //<-- this is what you are missing
MyItem.Colour = "blue";
MyList.Add(MyItem);
```

HTH, but your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: I'm using that code to read the stream; inside the while statement i've got a switch case block to send processing to different routines depending on what type of line that is.

Comment: ahh, I see now your question is buried in the middle.

Comment: @andrew please let me know if that sends you in the right direction.  If not you should remove as much extraneousness information from your question as possible and focus on the parts that directly relate to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Ah.. I see what you're doing with myJob and new Job(); that may work; i'll give it a go and report back; thanks.

Comment: Doh ! I think i'm right on it now; declare it once, but need to do the new() bit before re-using each time.

Answer (score 4):

A better way to read a file in the case will be to use a StreamReader that wraps the FileStream you read from. The StreamReader allows you to iterate through the file line per line without reading in the entire file beforehand.

So you can do something like this:

while((var line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  // Iterate through the file here
}

Inside the while loop you can devise a simple state machine that either reads a header, a Job or the jobs Details depending on where you are in the file.